# Why is the firewall off by default?

Tags: firewall

Why does eOS come with the firewall turned off by default?

Does turning it on do anything?

Comment: Are you asking for the design rationale? Might be better off asking the devs directly in that case. Turning on a firewall would do what one would expect from a firewall, no?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it's also off by default in Ubuntu and it's the same thing (ufw). 
More answers here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/22667/why-is-the-firewall-disabled-by-default
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DoINeedAFirewall